# How to access the source directory in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I am currently trying to create a plugin-like library for my company.

I need to check if four directories exist within the project structure. As `java.io.File` is not available, I am pretty confused on how to check for existance of a file that needs to exist within the project structure?

The concrete use-case.

There will be four directories:

```
/entities
/converter
/attributes
/caches
```

Now if the developer uses this library and wants to access all, lets say "Person"-Entities from the server, he should be able to call

```
RestGet.getAll("Person");
```

and the library looks in the source directory of the project if there are these Files:

```
/entities/PersonEntity.java       //<-- Stores the actual data
/converter/PersonConverter.java   //<-- Converts the JSON answer of the server to the Object
/attributes/PersonAttributes.java //<-- An enum that is used to set the attributes of the object
/caches/PersonCache.java          //<-- A simple Cache
```

How can I do this? I tried with `FileSystemStorage`, but it only tell me that I should use `getAppHome()`...

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the usage of the source directory which obviously won't exist on the device where your application is running.

You can get access to files in the root of your SRC directory which get packaged into the JAR using `Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(...)`.

The replacement to `java.io.File` is [FileSystemStorage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/FileSystemStorage.html) which is covered in [the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html).